# Is electrolysis with AC current possible?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electricity

Optimizing everything else, would efficient electrolysis be possible with AC current? Most sources suggest to use DC, but can the water still be split/disassociated with AC?

Comment: It would work, but you'd alternately be generating hydrogen and then oxygen at each electrode. You really want to mix hydrogen and oxygen? It goes BOOM really easily.

Comment: Especially when electricity is involved... but it could be a sort of water filled AC charged power cell, or something. The gas is stored until needed and then is exploded. However, you would have to be careful about energy fluctuation and electrical surges.

Comment: In addition to what MaxW wrote you would not expect electrolysis throughout the wave, only when the voltage exceeds the redox potential, so it would be less efficient. Also, AC can mean a lot of things. It would also depend on the frequency.

Comment: I found a similar question with the answer I was looking for: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62980/high-voltage-ac-water-electrolysis-not-working?rq=1